# NodeJS Socket.io - Sending works, receinving not

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a strange problem with NodeJS/Socket.io and I hope someone could help me.

I've developed a NodeJS server app which listen to port 1081. It works perfectly: when a device contacts port 1081, the server app save the TCP connection and, from that moment, app and device can communicate with each other.

Instead, when I make the server app listening to port 1080, this strange thing happens: device contacts the server through port 1080, the server app recevive the request and save the TCP connection. Now, the server app can successfully comunicate with the device, but when the device replies, the server app doesn't receive the answer. It looks as if there was something in port 1080 that blocks device answers, but ports 1080 and 1081 should be identical.

Has someone an idea about what's happening?

Comment: You're going to need to provide more information: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you replicate after killing all node proceses?

Comment: Paste your code please.